# Will my intent service get destroyed if

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice

If I have a broadcast receiver registered and unregistered with the life-cycle of my intent service, will the code inside onReceive (receiver) be executed, if the code inside onHandleIntent (service) gets complete before a broadcast is heard. The broadcast it is listening for is system generated and may take any time to be generated. So, essentially I have to wait for an indefinite amount of time. 
This service will also run when my app is not in the foreground.

So, will the receiver still be there to listen?

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? You have a `BroadcastReceiver` which you register and unregister according to the lifecycle of your `IntentService`. You're wondering if the code in `onReceive()` is going to be executed if the code in `onHandleIntent()` is completed before a broadcast comes in?

Answer (score 1):

Intent service stops itself when  its work is completed on onHandleIntent().
If you send the broadcast within the process of onHandleIntent()..then the onReceive() method is executed..
Else onReceive() is never called..

Answer (score 0):

No, IntentService is not the kind of Service which is meant to be kept alive, it stops when the last Intent has been processed.

If the Broadcast may arrive at any moment, register a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest.